# Marklogic include function in the custom transformation module

Tags: javascript, marklogic, transformation, marklogic-dhf, mlcp

In the  given function of custom transformation module how to call the DHF transformation module for MLCP(/data-hub/5/transforms/mlcp-flow-transform.sjs) in order to add the envelope in the output document?

```
function rewriteURI(content, context)
{
  content.uri = sem.uuidString() + "-" + content.uri;
  return content;
};
exports.transform = rewriteURI;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the DHF transform module with `require()` and then inside your custom transform, after modifying and setting the `content.uri`, invoke and return that DHF MLCP flow `transform()`.

```
const MLCPFlow = require("/data-hub/5/transforms/mlcp-flow-transform.sjs")
function rewriteURI(content, context)
{
  content.uri = sem.uuidString() + "-" + content.uri;
  return MLCPFlow.transform(content,context);
};
exports.transform = rewriteURI;
```